# Visual Studio changes control property whenever there any changes in form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Im working on a winforms app. I have a form called "MainForm" which contains user control. There is a checkbox in the user control, that should be hidden in some scenarios - thats why I made a property for it. The problem is that whenever I open the mainform, and make any changes in it the designer changes that property to false, so the checkbox in control is not visible.

Is there any way to prevent that behavior?
(I'm using VS2012)

UPDATE:

In codebehind of my control I have a propeprty

```
 public bool IsWebOmmitVisable
    {
        get { return ommitCheckBox.Visible; }
        set { ommitCheckBox.Visible = value; }
    }
```

In the constructor of control I set it to true:

```
 public myControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IsWebOmmitVisable = true;
...
```

However it looks like it doesn't matter.
Then I add this control to MainForm. The property is visible in properties of control. However whenever I modify any of the elements in MainForm, the property is set to false.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fSvQ.jpg

Comment: how you set visible to false? you need to set it in the part which is not auto-generated by VS

Comment: Share the code of that property.

Comment: As this question currently stands there is not enough information to answer without the code of your property. If I would take a guess, you need to make it so that it defaults to true using Attributes ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx)

Comment: Code which you shared doesn't reproduce the problem. Post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the problem.

Comment: BTW, remember that it's "Visible" and "Omit" (if you mean to skip something).

Comment: @RezaAghaei Sorry for that. I'm kinda aware that the code I provided wouldn't probably be enough to reproduce behavior that I described, but I counted on that there might eventually be people who faced the same problem. Tbh, I'm not even sure what was the source of my that weird behaviour and posting entire project was not an option. Luckily answer provided by MarkHall solved my problem.

Comment: No problem. But if you use `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden` you will loose the ability to set `IsWebOmmitVisable` at designer because the value will not be serialized and always return the `ommitCheckBox.Visible`, unless the `ommitCheckBox` be public.

Comment: I believe if `ommitCheckBox` is private/protected, you don't need any change and your property is OK. The default modifier for the `ommitCheckBox` is private and that's why I said it doesn't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute.aspx) will prevent the property from being serialized in the designer.

```
   [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public bool IsWebOmmitVisable
    {
        get { return ommitCheckBox.Visible; }
        set { ommitCheckBox.Visible = value; }
    }
```

From link:

> With the DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute, you can indicate whether the value for a property is Visible, and should be persisted in initialization code, Hidden, and should not be persisted in initialization code, or consists of Content, which should have initialization code generated for each public, not hidden property of the object assigned to the property.
>   **Members that do not have a DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute will be treated as though they have a DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute with a value of Visible.** The values of a property marked as Visible will be serialized, if possible, by a serializer for the type. To specify custom serialization for a particular type or property, use the DesignerSerializerAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

In the properties window select the class of the mainform, then click on the events tab (lightning icon) then double click in the load event, this will add a load event in the form, here you can set visible to false or true as you wish for the checkbox control

```
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mycheckbox.Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[simple form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tawJx.png)

and code inside the Form1.cs

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Visible = false;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Visible = !textBox1.Visible;
}
```

And it works perfectly as it should. (Button toggles the `Visible` property of the textbox.) I am not sure at what step you went wrong.

The `Form1_Load` was autogenerated by double clicking form title in the designer.

The `button1_Click` was autogenerated by double clicking the button1 in the designer.